# SQL Server stored procedure, invalid syntax

Tags: sql-server

I am not really a SQL man, but I have to alter a stored procedure where I have to add a column_name, `CrossbarRouter`, to the stored procedure.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [StateMachine].[UpdateSnapshots] 
    @SystemName[NVARCHAR](128), 
    @IntrestingEvents VARCHAR(128), 
    @StateMachine_JSON [NVARCHAR](MAX),
    @StateMachine_Object [NVARCHAR](MAX),
    @CrossbarRouter VARCHAR(128)
AS
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [DVMT30_EVENT_PROCESSOR].[StateMachine].[Snapshots] 
               WHERE SystemName = @SystemName)
        UPDATE [DVMT30_EVENT_PROCESSOR].[StateMachine].[Snapshots]
        SET IntrestingEvents = @IntrestingEvents, 
            StateMachine_JSON = @StateMachine_JSON, 
            StateMachine_Object = @StateMachine_Object, 
            CrossbarRouter = @CrossbarRouter
        WHERE SystemName = @SystemName;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO [DVMT30_EVENT_PROCESSOR].[StateMachine].[Snapshots] (SystemName, IntrestingEvents, StateMachine_JSON, StateMachine_Object, CrossbarRouter)
        VALUES (@SystemName, @IntrestingEvents, @StateMachine_JSON, @StateMachine_Object, @CrossbarRouter);

GO
```

Error

```
12:40:04 PMStarted executing query at Line 1
Commands completed successfully.
12:40:04 PMStarted executing query at Line 2
Commands completed successfully.
12:40:04 PMStarted executing query at Line 4
```

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure UpdateSnapshots, Line 9
>   Invalid column name 'CrossbarRouter'.

Prior to that I did make changes to table, which were like this.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [StateMachine].[Snapshots]
(
    [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SystemName] [NVARCHAR](128) NOT NULL,
    [IntrestingEvents] [VARCHAR](128) NOT NULL,
    [StateMachine_JSON] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NOT NULL,
    [StateMachine_Object] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NOT NULL,
    [CrossbarRouter] [VARCHAR](1) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Considering that you reference the database of `[StateMachine].[Snapshots]` in your SP, and didn't in your `CREATE`, that implies that you created the object in the wrong database; and that it already existed in whatever database `[StateMachine].[UpdateSnapshots]` is in, without the column `CrossbarRouter`.

Comment: Is there a reason the table uses CrossbarRouter VARCHAR(1) when the proc accepts @CrossbarRouter VARCHAR(128)? Probably not the cause of your problem but it could easily become one.

Comment: Otherwise, I'd say double/triple check your connections. Check that all of your changes saved by scripting out the table and stored proc again. Nothing looks wrong at a glance.

Answer (score 0):

You did not alter the table with the create table statement. You can add a column to an existing table with alter table add column statement or by dropping the table and then creating the table. A create statement on an existing table results in an error.